# reverse animation in Anime.js not working properly

Tags: javascript, forms, anime.js

I have a form which allows users to signup or login to their accounts. I am attempting to use anime.js to transition from the signup form to the login form (vice versa).

Initially I would like translateX property to be 0 which is signup, if the user has an account and wants to login the animation should transition on translateX to 420.

The issue I am having is the initial position on translateX is 420. I attempt to resolve this by calling reverseAnime.play() when the page loads. However I would much rather have the translate position at 0 initial and transition to position 420.

I have included a sandbox for clearer understanding.

[code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-framework-p9mi5?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

After further research (google search) I found a solution using an older version of anime.js (2.0.2). I applied it to my project and it worked! Yay! I'm not sure if the latest version has a bug, but using reverse (view sandbox example above) did not work for me.

If anyone has more information and can tell me what I was doing incorrectly or confirm the latest version (3.2.1) as of today (10/28/20) does or does not have a bug that would be helpful as well.

```
// const staticPanel = document.querySelector(".panel--static");
const slidingPanel = document.querySelector(".panel--sliding");

const signupBtn = document.querySelector(".signup");
// console.log(signupBtn);
const loginBtn = document.querySelector(".login");
// console.log(loginBtn);

const signupContent = document.querySelector(".panel__content.signup");
const loginContent = document.querySelector(".panel__content.login");

let animation = anime({
  targets: slidingPanel,
  translateX: "92%",
  elasticity: 100,
  autoplay: false,
});

let animationReverse = anime({
  targets: slidingPanel,
  translateX: "92%",
  elasticity: 100,
  direction: "reverse",
  autoplay: false,
});


loginBtn.onclick = () => {
  animation.restart();
  loginContent.classList.replace("hide", "show");
  signupContent.classList.add("hide");
};

signupBtn.onclick = () => {
  animationReverse.restart();
  signupContent.classList.replace("hide", "show");
  loginContent.classList.add("hide");
};
```